# Making sure I get a mouse up event for every mouse down

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

The code below draws a rectangle on every mouse move after the mouse button is pressed. When the user releases the mouse it should stop drawing.

I am trying to figure out how to make sure that drawing stops if the user releases the mouse outside the canvas element.

I thought that I could accomplish this by setting `onmouseup` event handler on my event inside `onmousedown` like this:

`canvas.onmousedown = function (e) {
  drawing = true;
  e.onmouseup = function (v) { drawing = false; }
};`

but it did not work because `e.onmouseup` is never called. So I ended up setting `window.onmouseup` instead.

Questions:

1. why was my `e.onmouseup` never called?
2. is my final solution the best way to do it?

`<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      drawing = false;

      function on_load(e) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

        canvas.onmousedown = function (e) { drawing = true; };

        canvas.onmousemove = function (e) {
          if (drawing)
          {
            var x = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
            var y = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
            var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
            context.strokeRect(x, y, 10, 10);
          }
        };

        window.onmouseup = function (e) { drawing = false; };
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="on_load()">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500" style="border: 1px solid black;">
    </canvas>
  </body>
</html>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Why was my e.onmouseup never called?

`e` is an `Event` object. It doesn't have a defined behaviour for an `onmouseup` property

> 2. Is my final solution the best way to do it?

Yes, but with some adjustments. First, consider if you really need the global variable. The same effect can be achieved without the global variable, but it might useful to keep it global for debugging purposes.

Second, your not-working code is not needed. It's better to have one always-existing event listener which only changes a harmless variable, than constructing a new event listener for each `mouseup` event. Besides, in your "wanted" code, the previous `mouseup` event is never explicitly removed.

```
 function on_load(e) {
    var drawing = false; // <-- Always declare variables
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.onmousedown = function (e) { drawing = true; };
    canvas.onmousemove = function (e) {
      if (drawing) {
        var x = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
        var y = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.strokeRect(x, y, 10, 10);
      }
    };
    window.onmouseup = function (e) { drawing = false; };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider an `onmouseout` handler to stop drawing when the mouse leaves your element.

Answer (score 0):

How can an OS guarantee anything like a balanced mouse down/up in some widget. Then if you get it working on OS/browser 'X' how do you know that OS/browser 'i' or OS/browser 'W' will all work the same way? There are a lot of reasons why you need to do something else, like even a timer. Likely the overhead of a timer would be small compared to what you want to do.